# How to use print method inside native iOS code in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, console, console.log

I'm trying to use print method in native iOS code in Flutter project.

This is how I tried:

```
print("")
debugPrint("")
OSLog("")
```

But nothing printed anything to the console!

How can I do that?

Comment: use NSLog, it is performance vice high. The all above command properties also work.

Comment: @PeterHaddad inside iOS module's code

Comment: Did you really not put anything between the quotes? That would result in nothing being logged.